# Navigation in React Native doesn't work after page refresh

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I set up the react-native app with react-native-web. In this app I need to have navigation, so I added react-navigation/native package according to the [getting started guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started). In mobile platforms everything works well, but in browser navigation doesn't work as expected. When I just start the app, I can navigate from one page to another without any problem. But when I refresh any page, navigation returns me back to the first Stack.Screen component in Stack.Navigator list. And then, when I click on the Link to another page, nothing happens, no errors appears in console and route doesn't change.

So the navigation only works properly when I just launch the app and don't change the route and don't refresh the page.

Here my linking. I followed the [deep linking guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking)

```
const linking: LinkingOptions<{
  Auth: string;
  Home: string;
  Table: string;
  Loading: string;
}> = {
  prefixes: ['alfateacherapp://', 'http://'],
  config: {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    screens: {
      Auth: 'auth',
      Home: 'home',
      Table: 'table',
      Loading: 'loading',
    },
  },
};
```

Here my NavigationContainer:

```
<NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Loading />}>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    {isLoadedToken ? (
      token ? (
        // Screens for logged in users
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Table" component={Table} />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        // Auth screens
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />
        </Stack.Group>
      )
    ) : (
      <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={Loading} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

In Home and Table screens I just have the Link from react-navigation/native and Text from react-native.
Home:

```
<Text>Home</Text>
<Link to={{ screen: 'Table' }}>Link to Table</Link>
```

Table:

```
<Text>Table</Text>
<Link to={{ screen: 'Home' }}>Link to Home</Link>
```

How can I fix this behavior? I need to be able to refresh the page and stay on current route when I'm in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! There was some platform-specific code for rendering a web index file. The rootTag displayed the usual react App component when the platform was "web" and AppRegistry from react-native registered the app in all other cases. This was done to bypass the warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Teacher', () => App);

if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
  const rootTag = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  rootTag.render(<App />);
} else {
  AppRegistry.runApplication('Teacher', {
    initialProps: {},
    rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
  });
}
```

When I removed this condition and left only the way that react-native handles the application, everything started working properly.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Teacher', () => App);

AppRegistry.runApplication('Teacher', {
  initialProps: {},
  rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the URL gets reset after you refresh since you're rendering the `Loading` screen - React Navigation would adjust the URL to match the currently rendered screen.

You should avoid rendering the `NavigationContainer` before you determine whether the user is logged in or not, i.e. the `Loading` component shouldn't be a screen in the stack, but a component that you render directly.

```js
if (!isLoadedToken) {
  return <Loading />;
}

return (
  <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Loading />}>
```

The auth flow guide shows a similar approach: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately it didn't help me. I changed the code as follows
```
return isLoadedToken ? (
// here my NavigationContainer
: (
    <Loading />
  );
```

The behavior is still the same. When I start the app, everything works perfectly, but after refreshing the page, the page navigation stops working without any errors.

Comment: Can you create a demo on snack.expo.dev?

Comment: I figured it out! There was some platform-specific code for rendering a web index file. The rootTag displayed the usual react App component when the platform was "web" and AppRegistry from react-native registered the app in all other cases. This was done to bypass the warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. 

When I removed this condition and left only the way that react-native handles the application, everything started working properly.